# Issues making HTTPS request in Lua for ESP8266

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

How can I send data in ESP8266 using HTTPS POST with request body parameters?
I have tried to use HTTP and net/TLS modules provided at https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io.
I get these errors

> E:M 528 HTTP client: Disconnected with error: 46

Using TLS

```
srv = tls.createConnection()
srv:dns(api, function(conn, ip)
  api = ip
  print("TLS" .. api)
end)
srv:on("receive", function(sck, c)
  print(c .. "success tls")
end)
srv:on("connection", function(sck, c)
  sck:send("GET /test HTTP/1.1\r\n" ..
    "Host: " .. api .. "\r\n" ..
    "Connection: keep-alive\r\n" ..
    "Accept: */*\r\n" ..
    "\r\n")
end)
srv:connect(443, "demo.com")
```

HTTP module

```
http.post("https://demo.com/test", 'Content-Type:application/json\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n' { data }, function(code, data)
  if (code < 0) then
    print("Request Failed")
  else
    print(code)
    print(data)
  end
end)
```

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code where your error is occurring

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the firmware?

Comment: Using custom build of 2.0 Lua